# ORDER BY then Group By MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have a data for this :

[image]

i want a result for this :

```
Id nip golongan
1 1001 3B
3 1002 3C
```

get max(id) from golongan and then grouping by and then view nip and golongan

how to fix it  ??

```
SELECT nip,golongan FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_golongan ORDER BY id_golongan DESC) t GROUP BY nip,golongan
```

Comment: Why is the `order by` in the subquery? Why is there a subquery at all? Ordering the items before grouping them does not make sense. You want to order the resulting groups.

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment. Please clarify why you need to order before grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need this: (assuming that `id_golongan` column is unique)

```
select tbl_golongan.id_golongan, tbl_golongan.nip, golongan 
from tbl_golongan  
inner join (select max(id_golongan) as maxid from tbl_golongan  group by nip) t
on tbl_golongan.id_golongan = t.maxid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nip,golongan FROM tbl_golongan GROUP BY golongan ORDER BY id_golongan DESC
```

here first record will be of max id (id_golongan );

Or,

```
SELECT nip,golongan, MAX(id_golongan) as maxId FROM tbl_golongan GROUP BY golongan ORDER BY id_golongan DESC
```